# Error Rendering View PENDING_I18N: Unable to find composite component root for composite component with id

Tags: jsf-2, attributes, initialization, components, composite

First of all, I'm a newby
I'm trying to implement a simple composite component in JSF 2. 
I wish to initialize an attribute of my CC from java code.

this is the using view:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:o3="http://emcube.it/components">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="#{testHome.getMarker()}" />
        </div>
            <h:panelGroup border="1">
                <div>
                <o3:basic id="idBasic" label="xxxEtichetta" value="VALORE"/>
                <!-- 
                <o3:edit id="idCod" value="#{testHome.instance.codice}" label="Codice"/>
                    <h:inputText id="idCod" value="#{testHome.instance.codice}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Codice" for="idCod" style="width:100px;"/>
                 -->
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h:inputText id="idDes" value="#{testHome.instance.descrizione}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Descrizione" for="idDes"  style="width:100px;"/>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:commandButton action="#{testHome.persist()}" value="Salva"/>
                <h:commandButton action="#{testHome.leave()}" value="Esci"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
        <div>
            <h:messages id="msgid" showSummary="true" 
                        showDetail="true"
                        errorStyle="color: #d20005" 
                        infoStyle="color: blue"/>
        </div>      
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

this is the composite Component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
<title>Not present in rendered output</title>
</head>
<body>
<cc:interface componentType="it.opencube.basicCC">
    <cc:attribute name="label" required="true" default="Etichetta"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.label}" for="#{cc.clientId}itext"/>
    <h:inputText id="#{cc.clientId}itext" value="{cc.attrs.value}"/>
</cc:implementation>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Component Class:

```
@FacesComponent("it.opencube.basicCC")
public class BasicCC extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    private String label;
    private String value;
//getters and setters here

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Entering encodeBegin");
        context.getAttributes().put("value", "NEW STRING VALUE");
        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }
    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }
```

and finally this is what I have in my taglib.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://emcube.it/components</namespace>
    <composite-library-name>components</composite-library-name>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>basic</tag-name>
        <component>
            <description>Componente di prova</description>
            <component-type>it.opencube.basicCC</component-type>
            <renderer-type>javax.faces.Composite</renderer-type>
            <!-- <handler-class>org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.TogglePanelTagHandler</handler-class> -->
        </component>
        <attribute>
            <description>Valore del componente</description>
            <name>value</name>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description>Etichetta del componente</description>
            <name>label</name>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

But when I run I get this error:

```
19:17:09,781 GRAVE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Error Rendering View[/testHome.xhtml]: java.io.IOException: PENDING_I18N: Unable to find composite  component root for composite component with id idBasic and class it.emcube.opencube.core.jsf2.components.BasicCC
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CompositeRenderer.encodeChildren(CompositeRenderer.java:73) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at it.emcube.opencube.core.jsf2.components.BasicCC.encodeChildren(BasicCC.java:59) [classes:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
```

I'm surely missing something basic in my example but I'm really not able to find it out by my self.
Thanks to anyone could help